# Using query_string search with post_filter

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

I'm trying to search for a city using query_string and asterix (`` query: `${city}*` ``) while also filtering the results by `countryId`. 
The query works well without filtering for countryId, but when adding the filter it finds nothing. Boty `city` and `countryId` were mapped as `text`.

Code:

```
const elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');

...

this.client = new elasticsearch.Client({
            hosts: [this._serviceUri]
        });

...

// The interesting part:
const results = await this.client.search({
            index: 'cities',
            body: {
                query: {
                    query_string: {
                        query: `${city}*`,
                        fields: ['city', 'countryId'],
                        // type: 'best_fields'
                    }
                },
                post_filter: { term: { countryId } }
            }
        });
```

How can I filter the results with post_filter or something alike correctly?

**UPDATE:**
Here is how the mapping looks like:

```
mappings: {
        _doc: {
            properties: {
                "city": {type: 'text'},
                "countryId": {type: 'text'}
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: why do you use post_filter and not bool/filter?

Comment: because it didnt work for me. i may have done something wrong with it.
would you be willing to show me an example? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way, without resorting to `post_filter`:

```
// The interesting part:
const results = await this.client.search({
        index: 'cities',
        body: {
            query: {
                bool: {
                    must: {
                        query_string: {
                            query: `${city}*`,
                            fields: ['city', 'countryId'],
                            // type: 'best_fields'
                        }
                    },
                    filter: {
                        term: { 
                            countryId: `${countryId}`,
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks but this also doesnt give me any result... could it have anything to do with the mapping? or what am i missing here? 
note that without the 'filter'-part it does give me results. but as I mentioned, I need them filtered by countryId

Comment: Please update your post with your mapping and a sample document that should match

Comment: I updated it. Thank you, it works now. had a typo in my last try. works perfectly!